# Why does the Deus in Mirai Nikki still exist?

Tags: mirai-nikki

In cycle 1, Yuno has become god and the Deus is dead, and after that, Yuno enters cycle 2. Why is Deus still alive after he is dead?

The same confusion also applies to the Deus in cycle 3. Cycle 3 takes place after Yuno and Yuki killed the other diary holders. At this moment, the Deus in cycle 2 has 'died' or become a red crystal-like stuff. How come in cycle 3, Deus still exists?

Furthermore, Deus is said to be the manipulator of space and time, both of which are eternal, and even so, they are mortal! The logic and causality of this premise seems quite messed up to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cycles 2 and 3 take place in alternate dimensions, each of which diverges from the previous cycle at a point before the survival game began. I believe the exact divergence point is somewhere around the time that Yuno killed her parents. Therefore, anyone who died over the course of the previous cycle is alive again in the next cycle. This is the *entire point* of Yuno creating those new cycles in the first place - so she can be with Yuki again after his death in Cycle 1, and his planned death in Cycle 2.

Naturally, the creation of each cycle also resurrected Deus along with everyone else, as time was reset back to a point where his powers hadn't yet degenerated.

Comment: In the ending part of the anime, it suggests that the god who creates a certain world would have a control of it just like Deus does. Since cycle 2 is created by Yuno, why doesn't she have control of it? I thought the relation of cycle 1 and cycle 2 is a nested structure, in another word, the world 2 is embedded in world 1. However, world 3 seems to be parallel to world 2 rather than created in world 2, because Yuno can get into world 3 before she becomes the god of world 2 (and at this point, she doesn't have the ability to create a world). The relation between world 1, 2, 3 is so confusing.

Comment: My personal understanding is that Yuno was the God of Cycle 1, but *only* of Cycle 1, and her powers didn't apply to Cycle 2, where Deus was still God. It's been too long since I watched the series for me to remember or understand how Cycle 3 came to be. I agree, it is all a bit confusing.